# iOS7 Xcode5 UICollectionViewController need spreadsheet style behavior with scrolling in both directions

Tags: ios, objective-c, grid, uicollectionview

I have a bunch of spreadsheet data i.e. columnns and rows.  I am able to display this in a UICollectionViewController.  However each row which is a section is wrapped.  How do I display the row cells horizontally with scrolling without being wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

For Cocoa Application `NSMatrix and NSCollectionView` is available.

For iOS NSMatrix and NSCollectionView is not available. so you need to create something custom using UICollectionView.

Comment: How do you customize UICollectionView to do the data grid spreadsheet style is what i am asking

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `UICollectionView`'s contentSize using method`- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize`. Since you know the size of a cell you could do something like

```
- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize
{
   // Scroll horizontally
   CGFloat contentWidth = self.maxNumberOfRows * self.widthForCell;

   CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth, self.bounds.size.height);
   return contentSize;
```

}

Comment: This wont horizontally scroll the section row cells.